# how set a a shortcut to elfeed filter

Tags: elfeed

When in press letter "b" within a elfeed search window,
the in-effect elfeed filter should change from
whatever it has (default -  @6-months-ago +unread)
to "foo"

How can I do it?

what I tried

```
(setq elfeed-search-filter "foo")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `elfeed-search-set-filter` non-interactively:

```
(elfeed-search-set-filter "foo")
```

Underneath, this boils down to something very similar to your attempt:

```
(with-current-buffer (elfeed-search-buffer)
   (setf elfeed-search-filter "foo")
   (elfeed-search-update :force))
```

If you want to make the "foo" filter have its own binding, you can wrap that `elfeed-search-set-filter` call into an interactive function and bind that to <kbd>b</kbd>:

```
(define-key elfeed-search-mode-map "b" #'<your function's name>)
```

Comment: this worked great!

Comment: the more I emacs, the more I fall in love